# z-index issue dropdown appear below content

Tags: css, z-index

Can't for the life of me figure out why the dropdown menus are displaying below the items on the top shelf. I've got the z-indexes and positions set right, i'm just missing something or got something in the wrong place.

Anyone help me out here.

Link to page: http://www.chelleon.co.uk/environ-skincare

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to apply a z-index to .header to get this working:

```
.header {
    .....
    z-index: 1;
}
```

The reason being that the elements you  want to put a z-index on's parent doesn't have a higher z-index than ones that are appearing above said element... `confused with my text, cus i am!`

Comment: heh he gets 2 ups and i get non :p

Answer (score 2):

The z-index on your `header` div is `z-index:1;`

The z-index on your `top-shelf-products` is `z-index:1;`

Change the div of your header to `z-index:2;`